# How to call map function with array of multiple types in typescript

Tags: typescript

I'm developing a Typescript function which needs to iterate over an array of type `Employee[] | Guest[]`.  The problem is that TypeScript is emitting the error `TS2349: This expression is not callable... has signatures but none of those are compatible with each other`.  I was expecting to be able to iterate the array and would just need to use a type guard before using the local variable, but that doesn't appear to be the case.  Is there a way I can use the `map` function without having to create a custom type?  The function will only ever need to iterate over the two types, so I was hoping to keep the parameter's type definition as `Employee[] | Guest[]`.  Below is a simple example where there's an error with `people.map`.

```
interface Employee {
  id: string;
  firstName: string;
}

interface Guest {
  firstName: string;
}

function getFirstNames(people: Employee[] | Guest[]): string[] {
  return people.map((x: Employee | Guest) => {
    return x.firstName;
  });
}

const employeeFirstNames = getFirstNames([
  {id: '1', firstName: 'Steve'},
  {id: '2', firstName: 'James'},
] as Employee[]);

const guestFirstNames = getFirstNames([
  {firstName: 'Mary'},
] as Guest[]);
```

Comment: https://duncanleung.com/typescript-array-map-over-union-array-type/

Comment: @ABOS, in order to prevent the details/constraints of the `map` function from being exposed to consumers, would it make sense to keep the function's signature as is then change the `map` line to `(people as (Employee|Guest)[]).map(...)`.  Because `map` is an implementation detail of the function, which shouldn't impact it's public interface.  If a `for` loop was used instead, we could keep the `Employee[] | Guest[]` type.

Comment: Chuck, please see answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use overload in this case, if you want to pass array with fixed element type

```
function getFirstNames(people: Employee[]): string[];
function getFirstNames(people: Guest[]): string[];
function getFirstNames(people: (Employee | Guest)[]): string[] {
  return people.map((x: Employee | Guest) => {
    return x.firstName;
  });
}
```

In this case, you won't be worried about public interface, so something like the following with mixed type will give error

```
const guestFirstNames = getFirstNames([
   { id: '1', firstName: 'Steve' },
  { firstName: 'Mary' }
]); // <-- No overload matches this call. Overload 1 of 2, '(people: Employee[]): string[]', gave the following error. Property 'id' is missing in type '{ firstName: string; }' but required in type 'Employee'. Overload 2 of 2, '(people: Guest[]): string[]', gave the following error. Type '{ id: string; firstName: string; }' is not assignable to type 'Guest'. Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'id' does not exist in type 'Guest'.
```

Answer (score 0):

Type the array as union of `Employee` and `Guest`.

```
function getFirstNames(people: (Employee | Guest)[]): string[] {
  return people.map((x: Employee | Guest) => x.firstName);
}
```

Comment: Won't that allow the mixing of types within the array?  For example, I could pass an array with both `Employee` and `Guest` types within that array.

Comment: It will indeed allow mixing up the types within the array. I don't think you can achieve the other way around. Is that an issue since the function only returns firstNames ? What would be the desired outcome if the array contains mixed types while the function doesn't allow it ?

Comment: `(Employee | Guest)[]` is different from `(Employee[] | Guest[]`, right? the former can be an array with mixed type elements, but the latter is homogeneous...

Comment: I guess it wouldn't really hurt to use the solution you provided.  It's just a concern from a typing perspective.  There should never be an array with both types in the code base, but having a function that accepts such an array hints that it could exist somewhere.

Answer (score -1):

What if I want to map over Employees only because they have more attributes like `emplyeeDepartment`:

```
function getEmplyeesOnly(people: (Employee | Guest)[]): string[] {
  return people.map((x: Employee | Guest) => x.emplyeeDepartment);
}
```